# MongoDB.Find on vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I am trying to make the following query to mongodb through the driver for VB.net but I have problems in the find option

db.collection.find({}.{_id:1})

thanks

my code

```
Dim mongo As New MongoClient(server)   
Dim db = mongo.GetDatabase(database)  
Dim collection = db.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)("test")  
Dim q = New BsonDocument()  
Dim f = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Projection.Include("_id") 'I think the problem is here'  
Dim list = collection.Find(filter:=q, options:=f).ToList
```

My idea is do the next SQL query, but I don't know how to call only the "_id" column.

```
SELECT _id FROM test
```

I found my mistake, it was in the last line of my code, here you can see the correction.

```
Dim list = collection.Find(q).Project(f).ToList
```

Comment: Care to share what those problems are or shall we guess?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: What's the exception or compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, it was in the last line of my code, here you can see the correction.

```
Dim list = collection.Find(q).Project(f).ToList
```